# Returning SQLite data depending on the current day - no results

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have written a method in my database class that searches the database depending on what day it is, however, even though the details are right there are no results.

Can anyone see why it won't return anything? I've tried about 15 different variations in the SQL Query so I'm pretty stuck!

The method is as follows in my **DB.java**:

```
public List<tableModules> getModuleTime(String module1, String module2, String module3, String day) {
        List<tableModules> moduleList = new ArrayList<tableModules>();
        // Select All Query     
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();        
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT modulename, modulelecturetime, moduleseminartime FROM " + Table2 + " WHERE (modulename=? OR modulename=? OR modulename=?) AND (modulelecturedate=? OR moduleseminardate=?)", new String[]{module1, module2, module3, day, day});    
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                tableModules module = new tableModules();
                module.modulename = cursor.getString(0);
                module.modulelecturedate = cursor.getString(1);
                module.moduleseminardate = cursor.getString(2);
                moduleList.add(module);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("Cant", "Find any lectures today");
        }   
        // return contact list
        return moduleList;      
    }
```

I then use this method in **MainActivity** to sub the data in:

```
public void getTodaysModules(String sessionName)
    {
        List<tableStudents> studentModules = db.getStudentsModules(sessionName);    
        if (!studentModules.isEmpty())
        {           
        for (tableStudents session: studentModules)
        {
            //Save modules to string
            String module1 = session.modules.toString();
            String module2 = session.modules1.toString();
            String module3 = session.modules2.toString();           
            String today = getCurrentDay().toString();          
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Today is: " + today, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            TextView event1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.event1);
            event1.setText(today + "'s Events:");
            List<tableModules> moduleDayList = db.getModuleTime(module1, module2, module3, today);
              for (tableModules module: moduleDayList) {                    

                  if(!module.modulelecturedate.isEmpty())
                  {                      
                      event1.setText("Your Lecture for" + module.modulename.toString() + "is at" + module.modulelecturetime.toString());
                  }                   
                  if (!module.moduleseminardate.isEmpty())
                  {                 
                      event1.setText("Your Seminar for" + module.modulename.toString() + "is at" + module.moduleseminartime.toString());
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      event1.setText("You have no seminars/lectures today");
                  }             
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "N", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();           
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your SQL is a readable way:

```java
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT modulename, modulelecturetime, moduleseminartime" +
                             " FROM " + Table2 +
                            " WHERE modulename=?" +
                               " OR modulename=?" +
                               " OR modulename=?" +
                              " AND (modulelecturedate=?" +
                                " OR moduleseminardate=?)",
                            new String[]{module1, module2, module3, day});
```

As you will notice, there are 5 markers, but you only supply 4 values.

Also, remember that `AND` has higher precedence then `OR`, so the SQL is actually:

```sql
SELECT modulename, modulelecturetime, moduleseminartime
  FROM xxx
 WHERE modulename=?
    OR modulename=?
    OR ( modulename=?
     AND ( modulelecturedate=? OR moduleseminardate=? ) )
```

Is that what you intended? I'd assume you would want:

```sql
SELECT modulename, modulelecturetime, moduleseminartime
  FROM xxx
 WHERE ( modulename=? OR modulename=? OR modulename=? )
   AND ( modulelecturedate=? OR moduleseminardate=? )
```

Comment: I originally had 5 values, however got the same results

Comment: Are the two date columns really `VARCHAR`? If not, why is `day` a `String`? Also, are they pure dates, or date+time?

Comment: No, I saved everything in my database as a string!

Comment: They're just two seperate strings that I've put data into, I haven't used datetime or anything

Comment: @MattMurphy Well, then, either your parameters are not what you think they are (e.g. trailing spaces will mess it up), or your database doesn't have any records matching those parameters. Did you debug/log to see the exact parameters? Did you try to run the SQL directly/manually using those values?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a 'day' in the selectionArgs array. You have five '?' and only four args. It should give you a message if you check your logs.

Comment: I originally had an extra "day" in there, however it had the same results